# PHP loop to get option groups on HTML dropdown

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a MySQL table with headers "courseid", "world" and "name".
I am trying to populate an HTML dropdown box via a PHP loop and I can not get it to work.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT courseid, world, name FROM courses ORDER BY world DESC, name ASC";
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $world = '';
        if ($world != $row['world']) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['courseid'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';   
        }else{
            echo '<optgroup label="'.$row['world'].'">';            
        }
    }
    echo '</select>';   
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$link->close();
?>
```

I would like it to loop through the whole table and display as follows:

```
<optgroup label"world1">
 <option value="courseid1">name1</option>
 <option value="courseid2">name2</option>
 <option value="courseid3">name3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label"world2">
 <option value="courseid4">name1</option>
 <option value="courseid5">name2</option>
 <option value="courseid6">name3</option>
</optgroup>
```

(courseid, world and name are values from the table)

Comment: What are the results you get? Where is `$link` set?

Comment: Make it a habit and use `htmlspecialchars` before inject into the HTML, even if the data came from your DB. `echo "<option>" . htmlspecialchars($row['name']) . "</option>"`

Comment: I saw the htmlspecialchars in an example somewhere but have never come across it before and didn’t understand what it was.... new to PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues. Firstly, you need to move `$world = '';` before your `while` loop, otherwise it will cause the `if` test to always be true. Secondly, the `if` test should *only* be used to test whether to finish an old and start a new `optgroup`, not to decide whether to output an `option`. This should work:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo '<select>';
    $world = '';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
        if ($world != $row['world']) {
            if ($world != '') echo '</optgroup>';
            echo '<optgroup label="'.$row['world'].'">';
            $world = $row['world'];
        }
        echo '<option value="'.$row['courseid'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';   
    }
    echo '</optgroup></select>';   
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```